# How to show tabs when DataBinding an IList<string> in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am successful in binding an IList to a DataGridView, and its working great, unless one of the strings includes a tab in the string, i.e. "\tTab here".

If this is the case the DataGridView will only show "Tab here" in the textbox cell. The value of the cell is "\tTab here", as when I edit the cell, the tab displays properly (added space in front of 'Tab here') but not when its not in edit mode.

How can I get the tab to show properly in the DGV?

Comment: You could expand the tabs yourself, in the CellFormatting event or draw the text in the CellPainting event.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "expend the tabs". DGV[col, row].Value includes the \t when I am in CellFormatting.  Do you mean replace the tab with spaces?  That doesn't look the same; When I select a cell, i put the value into a textbox. The textbox properly displays the tab, with one character. I was hoping for the same in the cell

Comment: One possibility. The other is to set the `Cell.Style.Padding` to the value you prefer. For example: `dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.Padding = new Padding([N], 0, 0, 0);` Where `[N]` (left padding) is a value you decide or you measure (measuring `\t = 8 x (char)32`). It depends on the reason why there's a `\t` there.

Comment: The tab could be in the center of the string as well, i.e. "Tab\there", and the cell will show "Tabhere", when I want it to show what a TextBox would display "Tab      here".  I did a Replace("\t", "              ") which seems to work for now, but this is not ideal as 8 spaces are not the same as a tab.